# swiftUI code sub routine/call simplification?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Swift 5, iOS 13, SwiftUI

Sorry, a noob question I am sure. How to write this so it doesn't look like a dogs dinner. The animations on both sides of the button are identical? How can I encode them more elegantly?

```
Button(action: {
      withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
        self.tLeft.toggle()
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
          self.tLeft.toggle()
        }
      })
      quest = quest + "1"
    }) { Wedge(startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 270)) .fill(Color.red) .frame(width: 200, height: 200) .offset(x: 95, y: 95).scaleEffect(self.tLeft ? 1.1 : 1.0)
    }.onReceive(rPublisher) { (_) in
      withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
        self.tLeft.toggle()
      }
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {
        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
          self.tLeft.toggle()
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just separate animations into dedicated private function, like below

```swift
var body: some View {
    ...
    Button(action: {
      self.animateTLeft() 
      quest = quest + "1"
    }) { Wedge(startAngle: .init(degrees: 180), endAngle: .init(degrees: 270)) 
             .fill(Color.red) 
             .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
             .offset(x: 95, y: 95)
             .scaleEffect(self.tLeft ? 1.1 : 1.0)
    }.onReceive(rPublisher) { _ in
      self.animateTLeft() 
    }
    ...
}

private func animateTLeft() {
  withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
    self.tLeft.toggle()
  }
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25, execute: {
    withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.25)){
      self.tLeft.toggle()
    }
  })
}
```